# Get paragraph field in a specific text format

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I have a landing page with a list of paragraphs. I'm trying to render the main body paragraph field as a summary to use in a metatag in the header.

`$basic_content_block->get('field_content')->first()->getValue();`

Returns:

```
[
    'value' => "<p><span><span><span><span><span><span>Some rich text here.</span></span></span></span></span></span><span",
    'format' => "basic_html"
]
```

How can I return this field as a teaser view, or more appropriately, a summary of just the text?

Comment: There is a module for that(TM): https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag (if you want it as metatag in header)

Comment: @Hudri that module doesn't support paragraph fields. it's a complex render array so i'm doing it programatically

Comment: Actually you should be able to use metatags with paragraphs. With tokens you can drill down to a nested paragraph with `entity`, e.g. something like `[node.paragraph_host_field.0.entity.field_body.0.value]`

Comment: @Hudri it adds a lot of complexity and management hassle. I'd rather just have it centralized in one preprocess_html hook. Additionally, i have a html.twig file which would need to access whatever the output of the metatag module is. Additionally, that doesn't address my original question on how to generate the actual summary of the field.

Answer (score 0):

```
$basic_content_block->get('field_content')->summary;
```

I believe that should do it.